# cant store image via fileupload control

Tags: upload

The code below its working very well but when i make new user and check in MS Sql i can find the new user that i enter it but without the image name and also cant store the image in the project file, please any help

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
string sc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}


protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
     cn.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string sqlstatment= "INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserInfo]"+
      " ([UID]"+
      " ,[FN] "+
      " ,[LN]" +
       ",[Password] "+
      " ,[RePass] "+
      " ,[Email] "+
      " ,[CountID] "+
      " ,[State] "+
      " ,[City] "+
      " , [Post] " +

      "  ,[Img]) values (@UID,@FN,@LN,@Password,@RePass,@Email,@CountID,@State,@City,@Post,@Img)";


     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

     cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;
     cmd.Connection = cn;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", fnbox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", lnamebox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxtbx1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePass", passtxtbx2.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountID", DDLCOUNTRY.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", DDLSTATE.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citytxtbox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post",postbox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", FileUpload1.FileName);

     if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
     {

         FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + FileUpload1.FileName));

     }



     SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
     ad.Fill(ds);
     Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");
}
```

}

Comment: does the image upload at all even if the name is not inserted into the database?

Comment: the image didnt upload at all also the name of the image didnt store in sql too

Comment: Are you using ASP.net FileUpload server control? or the plain old `<input type="file" />`?